# startActivityForResult is deprecated

Tags: java, android

Сел учить, но уроки старые и соответственно некоторые методы устарели. Если раньше при неявном выводе использовали такой код

```
intent = new Intent(this, ColorActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_COLOR);
```

то теперь так

```
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColorActivity.class);
                someMethod.launch(intent);
```

Вопрос. Как теперь мне передать переменную (int)REQUEST_CODE_COLOR?

Comment: https://google.gik-team.com/?q=startActivityForResult+is+deprecated

Comment: Теперь за место каждого `REQUEST_CODE_*` нужно регистрировать отдельный колбек (`registerForActivityResult(...)`). Соответственно использовать `REQUEST_CODE_*` не требуется, так как на каждый запрос будет вызываться свой колбек, а не один на всех `onActivityResult()`, как раньше.